# How to get LAN IP or Ethernet IP address in android

Tags: java, android, ethernet

Able to get the WI-FI IP address using the below code.

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

"EthernetManager" is not acceptable in the code, May I know how to get the IP address of the ethernet?

Comment: What do you consider to be the ethernet ip?

Comment: Wifi ip, lan ip, local ip, ethernet ip, internet ip,  public internet ip. Where are you after?

Comment: Have you tried `ConnectivityManager`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get LAN IP the following way:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        LinkProperties props = manager.getLinkProperties(manager.getActiveNetwork());
        props.getLinkAddresses() ; //May be array. Contains lan ips
```

This will give you an array of local IP addresses including IPv6.So depending on what you require you need to manually get the desired IP inside the array. Also, make sure you have added android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in Android Manifest.